# webRTC not working in Google Chrome but works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

While working on making a sample webRTC application for peer to peer video transfer I came across following issues:

**Environment Info:**

Google Chrome Version: 103.0.5060.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Firefox Version: 91.11.0esr (64-bit)

For sending/receiving Session Descriptor and ICE candidates I have written a raw Signalling Server in JAVA EE jax-rs, I am sure websockets would have been better choice to do so, but I am also practising Micro services using Java EE these days, so that is the reason.

Basically whenever my webRTC clients createOffer/createAnswer they POST their SDP and Candidates to server and GET peer's SDP and ICE Candidates respectively.

Also I have to allow Insecure content in my both browsers in scenario when I host my web application on a secured Apache web server, since my signalling server is running on plain http thus we cannot make AJAX **GET POST** to un-secured site(HTTP signalling server) from a secured site (application hosted on HTTPS).

**Scenario 1 (webRTC application running without a Webserver(plain file:///) and without any STUN server configured):**

**Google Chrome:**

- Open 2 instances of chrome
- Do the startCall()/createOffer() flow in one window and I see only below candidates gets generated:

```
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:3869243209 1 udp 2113937151 f9b4fb82-60fc-4059-ab69-a5d4ea18a167.local 35652 typ host generation 0 ufrag ZHj1 network-cost 999\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:398702138 1 udp 2113939711 95b69b6b-e522-42ec-a31b-1493529f196a.local 33073 typ host generation 0 ufrag ZHj1 network-cost 999\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:398702138 1 udp 2113939711 95b69b6b-e522-42ec-a31b-1493529f196a.local 55200 typ host generation 0 ufrag ZHj1 network-cost 999\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:3869243209 1 udp 2113937151 f9b4fb82-60fc-4059-ab69-a5d4ea18a167.local 52172 typ host generation 0 ufrag ZHj1 network-cost 999\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0}"
```

- Then did the joinCall()/createAnswer() flow in other window respectively and I see below candidates getting generated:

```
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:3869243209 1 udp 2113937151 ca7c5b87-8c6a-4f0e-9e08-d5d7f16ba134.local 33730 typ host generation 0 ufrag mekv network-cost 999\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:398702138 1 udp 2113939711 d6574d61-65f7-4038-a2c2-df55168c4066.local 40840 typ host generation 0 ufrag mekv network-cost 999\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0}"
```

- Finally, I **dont** see any video being transmitted from one chrome window to other.

**Firefox:**

- Open 2 instances of firefox
- Do the startCall()/createOffer() flow in one window and see only below candidates gets generated:

```
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:3 1 UDP 2122121471 2401:4900:1f25:ce2:8e:cec8:c258:aa12 34165 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:1 1 UDP 2121990399 192.168.122.1 45312 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:4 1 UDP 2122252543 2606:b400:c10:51:8000::7e0 60589 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:7 1 TCP 2105458943 10.191.213.54 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:0 2 UDP 2122055934 192.168.1.3 38799 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:1 2 UDP 2121990398 192.168.122.1 37762 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:2 1 UDP 2122187007 10.191.213.54 54023 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:9 1 TCP 2105524479 2606:b400:c10:51:8000::7e0 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:8 1 TCP 2105393407 2401:4900:1f25:ce2:8e:cec8:c258:aa12 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:3 2 UDP 2122121470 2401:4900:1f25:ce2:8e:cec8:c258:aa12 41108 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:2 2 UDP 2122187006 10.191.213.54 45971 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:4 2 UDP 2122252542 2606:b400:c10:51:8000::7e0 59139 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:5 2 TCP 2105327870 192.168.1.3 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:7 2 TCP 2105458942 10.191.213.54 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:8 2 TCP 2105393406 2401:4900:1f25:ce2:8e:cec8:c258:aa12 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:9 2 TCP 2105524478 2606:b400:c10:51:8000::7e0 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:0 1 UDP 2122055935 192.168.1.3 37468 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:5 1 TCP 2105327871 192.168.1.3 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:0 1 UDP 2122055935 192.168.1.3 45600 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:1 1 UDP 2121990399 192.168.122.1 50261 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:6 2 TCP 2105262334 192.168.122.1 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:2 1 UDP 2122187007 10.191.213.54 34546 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:5 1 TCP 2105327871 192.168.1.3 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:4 1 UDP 2122252543 2606:b400:c10:51:8000::7e0 37581 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:3 1 UDP 2122121471 2401:4900:1f25:ce2:8e:cec8:c258:aa12 37766 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:8 1 TCP 2105393407 2401:4900:1f25:ce2:8e:cec8:c258:aa12 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:7 1 TCP 2105458943 10.191.213.54 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:6 1 TCP 2105262335 192.168.122.1 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:9 1 TCP 2105524479 2606:b400:c10:51:8000::7e0 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:0 2 UDP 2122055934 192.168.1.3 42771 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:3 2 UDP 2122121470 2401:4900:1f25:ce2:8e:cec8:c258:aa12 50868 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:1 2 UDP 2121990398 192.168.122.1 44075 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:6 1 TCP 2105262335 192.168.122.1 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:4 2 UDP 2122252542 2606:b400:c10:51:8000::7e0 46966 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:8 2 TCP 2105393406 2401:4900:1f25:ce2:8e:cec8:c258:aa12 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:6 2 TCP 2105262334 192.168.122.1 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:5 2 TCP 2105327870 192.168.1.3 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:7 2 TCP 2105458942 10.191.213.54 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:2 2 UDP 2122187006 10.191.213.54 55215 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:9 2 TCP 2105524478 2606:b400:c10:51:8000::7e0 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"6531acc5\"}"
```

- Then did the joinCall()/createAnswer() flow in other window respectively and I see below candidates getting generated:

```
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:0 1 UDP 2122187007 79a14e4c-8340-493b-9e47-f9cad1f71cc6.local 39146 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"b55a2b4a\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:1 1 UDP 2122252543 62312a96-ae15-4df9-a57e-37695d5bac73.local 47499 typ host\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"b55a2b4a\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:2 1 TCP 2105458943 79a14e4c-8340-493b-9e47-f9cad1f71cc6.local 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"b55a2b4a\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:3 1 TCP 2105524479 62312a96-ae15-4df9-a57e-37695d5bac73.local 9 typ host tcptype active\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"b55a2b4a\"}",
"{\"candidate\":\"\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0,\"usernameFragment\":\"b55a2b4a\"}"
```

- Finally, I **do** see video being transmitted from one firefox window to other.

So I believe since chrome was not able to generate required ICE Candidates thus video transfer does not happen in Google chrome, but firefox somehow generated lot of ICE candidates and video streaming works.

Another thing to notice here is that the window which is creating the offer is generating more ICE candidates and the window in which we create the answer is generating less ICE candidates almost half, any clue why it is like that. (This behaviour in both browsers)

**Scenario 2: (webRTC application hosted on a secured Apache webserver(HTTPS) and without using any STUN server):**

Web Server is hosted on a different machine on my network not the same system where I am running browser.

**Google Chrome:**

- Open 2 instances of chrome
- Do the startCall()/createOffer() flow in one window and see only below candidates gets generated:

```
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:449265700 1 udp 2122131711 2401:4900:1f25:ce2:8e:cec8:c258:aa12 36027 typ host generation 0 ufrag AGrS network-id 4 network-cost 10\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0}",
 "{\"candidate\":\"candidate:398702138 1 udp 2122262783 2606:b400:c10:51:8000::7e0 49590 typ host generation 0 ufrag AGrS network-id 2\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0}",
 "{\"candidate\":\"candidate:704553097 1 udp 2122063615 192.168.1.3 56063 typ host generation 0 ufrag AGrS network-id 3 network-cost 10\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0}",
 "{\"candidate\":\"candidate:3869243209 1 udp 2122194687 10.191.213.54 41368 typ host generation 0 ufrag AGrS network-id 1\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0}",
 "{\"candidate\":\"candidate:1497385674 1 tcp 1518283007 2606:b400:c10:51:8000::7e0 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag AGrS network-id 2\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0}",
 "{\"candidate\":\"candidate:398702138 1 udp 2122262783 2606:b400:c10:51:8000::7e0 48272 typ host generation 0 ufrag AGrS network-id 2\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1}",
 "{\"candidate\":\"candidate:449265700 1 udp 2122131711 2401:4900:1f25:ce2:8e:cec8:c258:aa12 53410 typ host generation 0 ufrag AGrS network-id 4 network-cost 10\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1}",
 "{\"candidate\":\"candidate:704553097 1 udp 2122063615 192.168.1.3 40103 typ host generation 0 ufrag AGrS network-id 3 network-cost 10\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1}",
 "{\"candidate\":\"candidate:3869243209 1 udp 2122194687 10.191.213.54 39676 typ host generation 0 ufrag AGrS network-id 1\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1}",
 "{\"candidate\":\"candidate:1497385674 1 tcp 1518283007 2606:b400:c10:51:8000::7e0 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag AGrS network-id 2\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1}",
 "{\"candidate\":\"candidate:1736268921 1 tcp 1518083839 192.168.1.3 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag AGrS network-id 3 network-cost 10\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0}",
 "{\"candidate\":\"candidate:2820410297 1 tcp 1518214911 10.191.213.54 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag AGrS network-id 1\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0}",
 "{\"candidate\":\"candidate:1736268921 1 tcp 1518083839 192.168.1.3 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag AGrS network-id 3 network-cost 10\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1}",
 "{\"candidate\":\"candidate:1413790932 1 tcp 1518151935 2401:4900:1f25:ce2:8e:cec8:c258:aa12 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag AGrS network-id 4 network-cost 10\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0}",
 "{\"candidate\":\"candidate:2820410297 1 tcp 1518214911 10.191.213.54 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag AGrS network-id 1\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1}",
 "{\"candidate\":\"candidate:1413790932 1 tcp 1518151935 2401:4900:1f25:ce2:8e:cec8:c258:aa12 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag AGrS network-id 4 network-cost 10\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1}"
```

- Then did the joinCall()/createAnswer() flow in other window respectively and I see below candidates getting generated:

```
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:449265700 1 udp 2122131711 2401:4900:1f25:ce2:8e:cec8:c258:aa12 47554 typ host generation 0 ufrag a+kq network-id 4 network-cost 10\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:704553097 1 udp 2122063615 192.168.1.3 41884 typ host generation 0 ufrag a+kq network-id 3 network-cost 10\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:398702138 1 udp 2122262783 2606:b400:c10:51:8000::7e0 43015 typ host generation 0 ufrag a+kq network-id 2\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0}",
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:3869243209 1 udp 2122194687 10.191.213.54 59739 typ host generation 0 ufrag a+kq network-id 1\",\"sdpMid\":\"0\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":0}"
```

- Finally, I **do** see video being transmitted from one chrome window to other.

Firefox:

Firefox works the same way whether I deploy my application on web server or run locally(file:///) without any web server, I see almost same number of candidates it generates with little different port numbers. Firefox works always.

**Scenario 3: (webRTC application running without a Webserver(plain file:///) and STUN server configured):**

I tested with 2 STUN servers coturn and stunman, both produce same results:

**Google Chrome:**

- When STUN configured I could see request being received from Google Chrome (in STUN server logs) as soon as I create a offer but looks like Google Chrome is ignoring response generated by my STUN server. As I dont see any **srflx** type candidates being generated.
- Video streaming not works.

**Firefox:**

- Firefox is indeed generating candidates of type **srflx** as can be seen below, when STUN configured:

```
"{\"candidate\":\"candidate:3 2 UDP 1685790718 10.191.213.54 60108 typ srflx raddr 192.168.122.1 rport 60108\",\"sdpMid\":\"1\",\"sdpMLineIndex\":1,\"usernameFragment\":\"383b1ed2\"}"
```

- Video Streaming Works.

**Scenario 4: (webRTC application hosted on a secured Apache webserver(HTTPS) and STUN server configured):**

Note: Now I am testing video streaming behind NAT, i.e. the 2 clients are running on 2 different machines. Like Machine 1 in Network A and Machine 2 in Network B. Both machines can access the Web server and the signalling server.

**Google Chrome:**

- Still Google could not generate no **srflx** candidates and hence video streaming not works.

**Firefox:**

- Firefox could generate **srflx** candidates and video streaming works.

Source Code JavaScript:

```
let c1 = document.querySelector('#createBtn');
let j1 = document.querySelector('#joinBtn');
let createRoomDiv = document.querySelector('#createRoomDiv');
let joinRoomDiv = document.querySelector('#joinRoomDiv');
let clientId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999) + 1);

// Signaling server details
let signaling_host = "http://localhost:8080";

const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

// show the create room div
c1.onclick = function() {
    joinRoomDiv.setAttribute('hidden', true);
    createRoomDiv.removeAttribute('hidden');
}

// show the join room div
j1.onclick = function() {
    createRoomDiv.setAttribute('hidden', true);
    joinRoomDiv.removeAttribute('hidden');
}

// DOM elements
let createRoom = document.querySelector('#createRoom');
let joinRoom = document.querySelector('#joinRoom');
let endCall = document.querySelector('#endCall');
let roomName = document.querySelector('#createRoomText');
let joinRoomName = document.querySelector('#joinRoomText');
let localVideoElement = document.querySelector('#localVideo');
let peerVideoElement = document.querySelector('#peerVideo');

let localStream = null;

let STUN = {
    'url': 'stun:100.77.48.222:3478',
};

let configuration = 
{
    iceServers: [STUN]
};

let conn = null;
let peerInfo = null;

createRoom.addEventListener('click', startCall);
joinRoom.addEventListener('click', joinCall);
endCall.addEventListener('click', deleteRoom);

async function startCall() {

    // get the room name
    let name = roomName.value;
    if (!name)
        return alert("Room Name Empty!");

    // get the local audio/video stream from respective devices
    localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true});

    // display local stream on the localVideo element
    localVideoElement.srcObject = localStream;
    createRoomDiv.setAttribute('hidden', true);

    // create RTCPeerConnection
    conn = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
    console.log("Created new RTCPeerConnection", conn);

    // define callbacks which will send room name - iceCandidate mapping to the signaling server
    conn.addEventListener('icecandidate', (event) => onIceCandidate(name, event));
    conn.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', (event) => onIceStateChange(event));
    
    // add my audio video track to the connection
    localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => conn.addTrack(track, localStream));

    // create offer
    let offerOptions = {
        offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
        offerToReceiveVideo: 1
    };
    conn.createOffer(offerOptions).then(function(offer) {
        onCreateOfferSuccess(name, offer);
    })
    .catch(function(reason) {
        console.log("Create Offer Error: ", reason);
    });

    // enable the end call button
    endCall.removeAttribute('hidden');
    
    // wait for peer to join
    peerInfo = await waitForPeer(name);
    
    console.log("Adding remote Session Descriptor and ICE Candidates");
    
    // set remote session description
    let remoteSd = new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(peerInfo.sdp));
    await conn.setRemoteDescription(remoteSd);

    // add the ICE candidates
    for (const candidate of peerInfo.candidates) {
        await conn.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(JSON.parse(candidate)));
    }
    
    console.log("Added remote Session Descriptor and ICE Candidates");
}


async function waitForPeer(roomName) {

    do {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'GET', 
            url: signaling_host + '/signaling_server/webapi/room/' + roomName + '/' + clientId + '/peerSessionInfo',
            success: function (result) {
                peerInfo = result;
                console.log(peerInfo);
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
        await sleep(5000);
    } while(peerInfo.name === "");

    return peerInfo;
}

async function onCreateOfferSuccess(name, offer)
{
    await conn.setLocalDescription(offer);
    console.log("Local Description:", offer);
    let data = {id: clientId, name: name, sdp: JSON.stringify(offer)};
    
    // send Session Descriptor to signaling server peer will fetch from there
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST', 
        url: signaling_host + '/signaling_server/webapi/room/create',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(result) { 
            console.log('Create Offer Success: ' + result); 
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + request.responseText);
            alert(request.responseText);
        },
        contentType: "application/json"
        //dataType: 'json'
    });
}

function onIceCandidate(name, event) {
    if(event.candidate !== null) {
        console.log("Send Candidate to server: ", event.candidate);
        let data = {id: clientId, name: name, candidate: JSON.stringify(event.candidate)}

        // send ICE Candidate to signaling server peer will fetch from there
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST', 
        url: signaling_host + '/signaling_server/webapi/room/icecandidate',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(result) { 
            console.log('Success: ' + result); 
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + request.responseText);
            alert(result.responseText);
        },
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
    }
    else {
        console.log("No more ICE Candidates, Session Created");
    }
}

function onIceStateChange(event) {
    console.log("Ice State Changed to: ", conn.iceConnectionState, event);
}

async function joinCall() {

    // room name user want to join
    let name = joinRoomName.value;
    if (!name)
        alert("Room name empty");

    joinRoomDiv.setAttribute('hidden', true);

    // get peer Info i.e. peer session descriptor and candidates
    peerInfo = await getPeerInfo(name, clientId);   

    // create RTC connection object
    conn = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

    // register event handlers
    conn.addEventListener('icecandidate', (event) => onIceCandidate(name, event));
    conn.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', (event) => onIceStateChange(event));
    conn.addEventListener('track', (event) => handleRemoteStream(event));

    // set remote session description
    let remoteSd = new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(peerInfo.sdp));
    await conn.setRemoteDescription(remoteSd);

    // add the ICE candidates
    for (const candidate of peerInfo.candidates) {
        await conn.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(JSON.parse(candidate)));
    }

    console.log("Added remote Session Descriptor and ICE Candidates");

    // create answer
    conn.createAnswer().then(function(answer) {
        onCreateAnswerSuccess(name, answer);
    })
    .catch(function(reason) {
        console.log("Create Answer Error: ", reason);
    });

    // enable the end call button
    endCall.removeAttribute('hidden');
}

function getPeerInfo(name, clientId) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'GET', 
            url: signaling_host + '/signaling_server/webapi/room/' + name + '/' + clientId + '/peerSessionInfo',
            success: function(result) {
                peerInfo = result;
                console.log("Got Peer Info: ", peerInfo);
                resolve(result);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                reject(err);
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });

    });
}

async function onCreateAnswerSuccess(name, answer)
{
    await conn.setLocalDescription(answer);
    console.log("Local Description:", answer);
    let data = {id: clientId, name: name, sdp: JSON.stringify(answer)};
    
    // send Session Descriptor to signaling server peer will fetch from there
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST', 
        url: signaling_host + '/signaling_server/webapi/room/join',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(result) { 
            console.log('Create Answer Success: ' + result); 
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + request.responseText);
            alert(request.responseText);
        },
        contentType: "application/json"
        //dataType: 'json'
    });
}

function handleRemoteStream(event) {
    console.log("handleRemoteStream called: ", event);
    if (peerVideoElement.srcObject !== event.streams[0]) {
        peerVideoElement.srcObject = event.streams[0];
        console.log("Received Remote Stream");
    }
}

function deleteRoom() {
    let name = "";
    if (roomName.value !== "")
        name = roomName.value;
    else
        name = joinRoomName.value;

    $.ajax({
        url: signaling_host + '/signaling_server/webapi/room/remove/' + name,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function(result) {
            console.log("Room Deleted: ", name);
        }
    });

    if (localStream) {
        localStream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
            track.stop();
        });
    }

    conn.close();
    
    localVideoElement.srcObject = null;
    peerVideoElement.srcObject = null;

    endCall.setAttribute('hidden', true);

    // stop waiting for peer now
    peerInfo.name = '.';

}
```

For Complete Source Code follow below git repo:
https://github.com/satyam1990/webrtc-sample

Just wondering what could be a possible reason behind Google Chrome not working in almost all scenarios except Scenario 2 and Firefox works all the time.